# Fedora 25 Live Persistent Overlay Not Working

Tags: fedora, overlayfs, persistence

I have just created a fresh Fedora 25 Xfce 32-bit Live USB using the following command:

```
livecd-iso-to-disk --noverify --reset-mbr --format --msdos \
--overlay-size-mb 1024 --home-size-mb 512 --unencrypted-home \
'/path/to/iso.iso' /dev/sdb1
```

However, the overlay doesn't seem to work on any of the 4 systems I've tried, e.g. if run a simple `dnf install stress` and reboot, I have to install the `stress` command again. The home persistent storage works perfectly fine.

How can I fix this?